# How can I fix Amazon EC2 instance stuck on "StatusCheckFailed"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I have "**INSTANCE Status Checks**" error every day. (1 Error/Day.)

**StatusCheck** checks two things :

1. System Status Checks
2. Instance Status Checks

My error is on "2".

So I created "*Alarm Status*" to Reboot my instance immediately on error. Otherwise, my instance freezes and does not restart itself.

That fixes my problem temporarily.

My instance is used for a Web Server and only for that.

Instance Type : *t2.micro* (1Gb RAM & 1 CPU) + 2Gb Swap (swappiness=60).

I am using Apache / PHP-7.x / Mysql.

- CPU average : **30%**
- MEM-RAM average : **400M**
- SWAP average : **1% - 10%**

So my question is, how do I fix "INSTANCE Status Checks" error?

On Amazon System Log :

```
[145790.666430] Out of memory: Kill process 5765 (apache2) score 175 or sacrifice child
[145790.674374] Killed process 5765 (apache2) total-vm:1010904kB, anon-rss:25148kB, file-rss:2240kB, shmem-rss:22216kB
[145816.058971] Out of memory: Kill process 5165 (apache2) score 163 or sacrifice child
[145816.064187] Killed process 5165 (apache2) total-vm:733332kB, anon-rss:24744kB, file-rss:2416kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[147177.790592] INFO: task apache2:6312 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[147177.796866]       Not tainted 4.15.0-1035-aws #37-Ubuntu
[147177.801836] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_s
```

For "*Out of memory: kill ....*"

I created a cron script to Restart Apache2 service on FailOver.

But, I think, it's not my Instance problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried completely stopping the instance and restarting it?  That would move it off it's current hypervisor.

Comment: Thanks for your response @kenlukas, yes of course that's the first thing I did.

Comment: UP Please ? I'have always this error..

Thanks in advanced.